# Storing and invoking a different kind of Action object in a single field

Tags: c#, delegates

I have multiple kinds of Action delegates. Take e.g.:

```
Action<float> floatAction;
Action<string> stringAction;
```

I want to store any one of them into one variable, and be able to invoke it later. Is that possible?

```
SomeSortOfType action = floatAction;
//or
SomeSortOfType action = stringAction;
SomeSortOfType.Invoke();
```

I could not find a basetype for the Action class, so I'm pretty clueless as to whether this is possible in a way.

Gr.Viller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class that is the base class for all delegate types.

For example:

```
Action<float> floatAction = (x) => Console.Write(x * 5);
Action<string> stringAction = Console.WriteLine;

Delegate d1 = floatAction;
d1.DynamicInvoke(4.3f);

d1 = stringAction;
d1.DynamicInvoke("Hello world");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Is there any kind of caveat with Delegate.DynamicInvoke instead of Action.Invoke, there's probably a reason for it not being there.

Comment: @Villermen the closest method is `DynamicInvoke`. you can call invoke using `d1.Method.Invoke` but then you need to provide additional parameters.I think the reason is that the compiler has no information about what this Delegate holds, therefore it can't just infer the types.so you should also be careful when using `DynamicInvoke`, you must provide correct arguments, otherwise you won't get any compile time error but in runtime it will throw an exception

Comment: So if I call DynamicInvoke on a Delegate that is actually an Action<something>, will it not supply the argument (something) with it?

Comment: yes it will pass the arguments, but it uses late-bounding which means this will not executed until runtime and isn't checked at compile-time whether it's valid or not, for example after `Delegate d1 = floatAction;` if you call dynamic invoke and pass a string: `d1.DynamicInvoke("Hello world")` you will get an exception at runtime not compile time.

Comment: Alright then this will work out great for me, thanks again =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `Action<dynamic>` (or `Action<object>` with casting) if you create new lambdas referencing your `Action<>`s:

```
Action<float> floatAction = x => Console.WriteLine(x*3);
Action<string> stringAction = Console.WriteLine;

Action<dynamic> dyn = o => floatAction(o);
dyn(1.5f);
dyn = o => stringAction(o);
dyn("Hello World!");
```

I'd say Selman22's solution is probably better, but I present this in case it's more useful to you.